# Should questions about system requirements be allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Should we allow questions about system requirements for a game? They may be indirectly related to that game, but more asking what their computer needs to play it. I'm struggling to see how questions like those have to be asked on our site, when a simple google search should provide answers. So my question is, why, and should we allow questions about system requirements?

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/756/system-specification-questions and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/can-i-ask-if-a-specific-game-will-run-on-a-specific-computer-system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Allowed"? Sure. We've had 'em before. We'l get 'em again. They're mostly 'acceptable', so long as they're not super-localized to a particular special snowflake of a hardware configuration.

"Downvoted mercilessly"? I agree with that also. They tend to reek of poor research effort, which is what the down vote button - not the close button - is for.